# NEXT.JS how to revalidate/refresh data

Tags: mongodb, next.js, page-refresh, swr

I am fetching data with getServerSideProps(), I cannot use revalidate: 10 ,it is usable only for getStaticProps. So, How can I revalidate/refresh my data from mongo?
I have btn on page, it change value in database but browser doesn't show it up.
If I refresh page then data show up.
I am trying to use SWR but I am doing something wrong.
Can you please show me solution. Thanks.

````
export async function getServerSideProps() {

  await db.connect();
  const x =  await Team.find({}).lean() 
  await db.disconnect();

   return {
    props: {
      dataX: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x))
    } // , revalidate :10   <=== dont work for getServSideProps 
  }
}


const Index = ( props ) => {

const { dataX } = props  // data from mongo

let w = []
  const fetcher = async () => {
  let m = []
  await axios('/api/getTeam/data')
  .then(res => {
    m = res.data
  })
   return m
  }

function dataSWR() {
 const {data, error} = SWR('dashboard', fetcher)

 if(error) return 'error'
 if(!data) return 'loading'
 w.push(data)
}

dataSWR()

console.log(w)    // I am getting first empty [] them data
 
[]
[Array(8)]

```
````

Answer (score 0):

export async function getStaticProps() {
const data = await fetchSomeData(); // Verileri getirme işlemi (örneğin, API çağrısı)

return {
props: {
data,
},
revalidate: 10, // Verileri her 10 saniyede bir yeniden doğrula
};
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).